# Importing data from url using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a json embedded on a gov.uk website (https://www.gov.uk/performance/g-cloud/cumulative-sales-by-company-size) as follows:

```
Import pandas as pd
html_data = pd.read_json("https://www.gov.uk/performance/g-cloud/cumulative-sales-by-company-size")
```

...but I get no joy.

Comment: Please edit the question in order to show what error are you receiving.

Comment: You can also click on the "download JSON" and use that url instead.

Answer (score 0):

The url you have supplied is not JSON.   In fact it doesn't look the the site is using JSON but is instead producing HTML table directly from server.

You can instead use pandas read_html in this case:

```
import pandas as pd
html_data = pd.read_html("https://www.gov.uk/performance/g-cloud/cumulative-sales-by-company-size")
html_data[0]
```

Comment: the url 
https://www.gov.uk/performance/g-cloud/cumulative-sales-by-company-size
return 404 ERROR means not found so this URL return HTML

Comment: link is now broken it used to return html with table

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190729231954/https://www.gov.uk/performance/g-cloud/cumulative-sales-by-company-size